# Angularjs service for directive is unknown if in same file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, angularjs-factory

***Error only if minimized and loaded in same file. 
If app.ts is loaded before Service or Directive it works.***

***(No problems with controllers)***

***How can i make it work?***

Console Error:

```
site.js:119 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e%20%3C-%20routeNavigation%20%3C-%20navigationDirective
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:50308/js/site.js:11:416
    at http://localhost:50308/js/site.js:48:7
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:50308/js/site.js:45:270)
    at http://localhost:50308/js/site.js:48:69
    at d (http://localhost:50308/js/site.js:45:270)
    at e (http://localhost:50308/js/site.js:46:1)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:50308/js/site.js:46:86)
    at Object.$get (http://localhost:50308/js/site.js:43:460)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:50308/js/site.js:46:295)(anonymous function) @ site.js:119
```

AngularJs Error Message:

```
Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- routeNavigation <- navigationDirective
```

app.ts

```
enter code here
"use strict";
var app = angular.module('HouseConcertApp', ['ngCookies', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ngRoute', 'houseconcertControllers', 'houseconcertServices', 'houseconcertDirectives']);

app.config([
'$translateProvider', '$routeProvider', function($translateProvider, $routeProvider) { ....
```

services.ts

```
var houseconcertServices = angular.module('houseconcertServices', []);

houseconcertServices.factory('routeNavigation', function ($route, $location) {
    var routes = [];
    angular.forEach($route.routes, function (route, path) {
        if (route.name) {
            routes.push({
                path: path,
                name: route.name
            });
        }
    });
    return {
        routes: routes,
        activeRoute: function (route) {
            return route.path === $location.path();
        }
    };
});
```

directives.ts

```
var houseconcertDirectives = angular.module("houseconcertDirectives", []);


houseconcertDirectives.directive('navigation', ['routeNavigation', routeNavigation => ({
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "navigation-directive-tpl.html",
    controller($scope) {
        $scope.routes = routeNavigation.routes;
        $scope.activeRoute = routeNavigation.activeRoute;
    }
})]);
```

index.html

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="HouseConcertApp">
    <head>
        <base href="/index.html">
        <title>House Concert</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Main.css"/>
        <script src="js/site.js" onload="Hc.Common.initialize()"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <navigation></navigation>

    <div ng-controller="HouseConcertCtrl">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

***it works if html head script includes like this:
but not if all in this order minimized in site.js (with gulp)***

```
<script src="pathToFolder/app.ts"></script>
<script src="pathToFolder/services.ts"></script>
<script src="pathToFolder/controllers.ts"></script>
<script src="pathToFolder/directives.ts"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get files `minified` without error you should make sure to follow Dependency Injection pattern consistently. Only `routeNavigation` factory code is missing DI Inline Array annotation in your code.

Change below

```
houseconcertServices.factory('routeNavigation', function ($route, $location) {
```

to

```
houseconcertServices.factory('routeNavigation',['$route', '$location', 
  function ($route, $location) {

     //service code will be as is.

}]);
```

[**Doc link**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation) for minification related warning

Comment: Thank you. This solved one Problem. But i have Problems getting scope data. I will edit the error message.

Comment: @Claudia what problem remains now?

Comment: My Navigation has no data.

Comment: there is now no data in navigation-tpl.html for ng-repeat="route in routes".

Comment: @Claudia if this answer solved your problem please accept it as correct answer and ask **another** question

Comment: @smnbbrv it didn't solve my problem completly. I am now a step further but the problem remains.

Comment: @Claudia, no, it **did** solve the problem initially asked by you. You told _Thank you. This solved one Problem. But i have Problems getting scope data._ and this means that now you have a totally different problem which has nothing to do with your first question

Comment: @smnbbrv ok. in this case i will try to rewind my question edit and ask a new one.

Comment: Found the second place where the DI pattern is needed.
controller($scope){  -> controller:['$scope' , function($scope){